# false || true giving 0 in MinGW Compiler v 6.3.0-1

Tags: c++, boolean, mingw, operator-precedence, mingw32

This is a C++ program I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "\n" << "false || false" << ": " << false || false;
    cout << "\n" << "false || true" <<  ": " << false || true;
    cout << "\n" << "true || false" << ": " <<  true || false;
    cout << "\n" << "true || true" << ": " <<  true || true;
    cout << "\n" << "false && false" << ": " << false && false;
    cout << "\n" << "false && true" << ": " << false && true;
    cout << "\n" << "true && false" << ": " << true && false;
    cout << "\n" << "true && true" << ": " << true && true;

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output.

```
false || false: 0
false || true: 0
true || false: 1
true || true: 1
false && false: 0
false && true: 0
true && false: 1
true && true: 1
```

Could someone explain to me why `false || true` is giving `0` ? I am using MinGW C++ Compiler version 6.3.0-1.

Comment: Wrap the expression in parenthesis.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Oh okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator<<` has higher precedence than `operator ||` (and `operator &&`), so `cout << false || true;` will be interpreted as if `(cout << false) || true;`; you'll always get `false` to be printed out.

To solve the issue you should add parentheses to specify the precedence explicitly, e.g. `cout << (false || true);`.

Comment: Ahh okay. Got it. Thanks a lot @songyuanyao.